# Most efficient way to clone database representation of tree in adjacency list model

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, algorithm, tree

I'm storing nested lists in my database using the adjacency list model. Each list might have 50-150 nodes, so we'll call it 100 nodes on average. The situation has come up where users want to clone a list (i.e., use an existing list as a template from which to create a new list). This use case could potentially save them a lot of time when new lists differ only slightly from existing lists.

Here's an abbreviated version of the table schema I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE Nodes (
    NodeId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ParentId int NULL,
    ListId int NOT NULL,
    NodeText varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

My original thought was to use an `INSERT ... SELECT` to copy all the nodes in one shot, but that leaves the new records referencing the old `ParentId` values.

I've got a solution that's working (in application code, not SQL), but it seems suboptimal due to the number of queries required. Here's the algorithm:

1. Select all records belonging to old list.
2. Iterate over rows and add to new list by inserting with different `ListId`.
3. Select `@@IDENTITY` from each insert and store it alongside data for current row.
4. Iterate over rows again and update `Nodes` table, setting `ParentId` to new ID (from previous step) where `ParentId` is equal to old ID and `ListId` is equal to new list ID.

Like I said, that works fine, but it requires 300+ queries to clone a single list containing 100 nodes. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: You can use an `OUTPUT` clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. `Id` values.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Comment: Neat! That will certainly eliminate the `SELECT @@IDENTITY` query following the `INSERT`, for about a 33% total reduction in queries. It's a good start.

Comment: Aside: `Scope_Identity()` is generally preferred to `@@Identity` since it is limited to the current scope. As you've already seen, `OUTPUT` is far more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The following solution is a zero loop, zero temp table one.

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db7e7/17)**

```
DECLARE @CurrentID int = IDENT_CURRENT('Nodes'),
        @OldListId int = 1,
        @NewListId int;

SELECT @NewListId = ISNULL(MAX(ListId) ,0)+1 FROM Nodes

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Nodes ON

;WITH NewNode as (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY NodeId)+ @CurrentID as NewNodeId, * 
    FROM Nodes WHERE ListId= @OldListId
)
INSERT INTO Nodes(NodeId,ParentId,ListId,NodeText)
SELECT N1.NewNodeId ,N2.NewNodeId , @NewListId, N1.NodeText FROM NewNode N1 LEFT OUTER JOIN NewNode N2 ON 
N1.ParentId = N2.NodeId

--SELECT N1.* , N2.NewNodeId as NewParentId FROM NewNode N1 LEFT OUTER JOIN NewNode N2 ON 
--N1.ParentId = N2.NodeId

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Nodes OFF
```

The above solution generates the tree and then inserts to the table. Please be aware to use appropriate transactions and locking mechanism to ensure the data is consistent

Comment: Very interesting. The only problem is that it breaks down when `NodeId`s aren't sequential, which is often the case. It seems like you would need a recursive CTE to establish the hierarchy before applying your solution.

Comment: @MattJacob I can't agree with you about breaking down. Can you show the break down scenario. Check this  [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b846/3) which has `nodeid` that is not sequential

Comment: I think you're right. I don't know what I was doing before, but now I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With suitable transaction wrapping and isolation, the following may meet your needs:

```
-- Set up some sample data.
declare @Nodes as Table ( NodeId Int Identity, ParentId Int Null, ListId Int, NodeText VarChar(255) );
insert into @Nodes ( ParentId, ListId, NodeText ) values
  ( NULL, 1, '1' ),
  ( 1, 1, '1.1' ), ( 1, 1, '1.2' ),
  ( NULL, 2, '2' ),
  ( 4, 2, '2.1' ), ( 5, 2, '2.1.1' );
select * from @Nodes;

declare @TemplateListId as Int = 2;
-- Assuming that the clone is a new List. This is not important to what follows.
declare @ListId as Int = Coalesce( ( select Max( ListId ) from @Nodes ), 0 ) + 1;

-- Copy the template rows into the table and generate a mapping from old to new NodeIds.
declare @Fixups as Table ( OldNodeId Int, NewNodeId Int );
with Template as (
  select NodeId, ParentId, ListId, NodeText
    from @Nodes
    where ListId = @TemplateListId )
merge into @Nodes as Nodes
  using Template as T
  on 42 < 0
  when not matched then
    insert ( ParentId, ListId, NodeText ) values ( ParentId, @ListId, NodeText )
    output T.NodeId, inserted.NodeId into @Fixups;
select * from @Nodes;
select * from @Fixups;

-- Apply the fixups to the new copy.
update Nodes
  set ParentId = Fixups.NewNodeId
  from @Nodes as Nodes inner join
    -- Update only the copy and not the template. (Could also use IN or EXISTS.)
    @Fixups as Copy on Copy.NewNodeId = Nodes.NodeId inner join
    -- Map the old nodes to the new.
    @Fixups as Fixups on Fixups.OldNodeId = Nodes.ParentId;
select * from @Nodes;
```